# Is It Safe to Remove InnoDB Log Files on a Production Environment?

Tags: mysql, jira, innodb-log-file-size

I'm trying to connect JIRA Software to a server that already has multiple databases and some of them are on production.

As Atlassian mentioned in their documentation on [Connecting JIRA to a Database](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/connecting-jira-applications-to-a-database-938846850.html), I have to change the **innodb_log_files_size** to be at least 2GB. Changing the log files size means that I need to shutdown mysqld, set the new log files size to 2GB, remove/backup the old files and let mysqld create new ones on start.

I have read that innodb log files includes tables structure and transactions information for the existing tables.

My question is that **is it safe to do so on a production environment?** Will I have any real-time errors when mysqld start again?

Thanks

Comment: I believe your question is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911551/mysql-how-to-change-innodb-log-file-size

Comment: Adding a remark to @GeraldSchneider's link: "shutdown mysql cleanly" probably requires the variable innodb_fast_shutdown to be 0 (rather than default 1). Always do backups anyway.

Comment: I've tried that method, but mysqld service failed to start and there was a new file created "ib_filelog101". I got the old log files back but still mysqld service won't start. I tried looking at mysqld.log but it's empty. What shall I do in this case?