# MySQL server unable to start after trying to change the innodb log file size

Tags: mysql

I posted a question 2 days ago [if it's safe to delete innodb log files](https://serverfault.com/questions/995035/is-it-safe-to-remove-innodb-log-files-on-a-production-environment) to change the innodb_log_file_size variable.

The answer was referencing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911551/mysql-how-to-change-innodb-log-file-size) and I did the following:

- Set innodb_fast_shutdown to 0 in "my.cnf" file
- Stopped mysqld service
- Backed up old log files (ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1) to tmp folder
- Removed old log files from /var/lib/mysql
- Started mysqld service - Failed to start
- Restored backup log files to /var/lib/mysql
- Started mysqld serice again, but also failed to start.

I found that log file **mysqld.log was empty**. I couldn't trace why
   mysqld failed to start again.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you restart mysql after changing `innodb_fast_shutdown` and before shutting it down finally?

Comment: No I didn't. After mysql service failed to start I assumed that this was the mistake I did.

Comment: Well, without restarting the config change you did wasn't active. So you stopped the service exactly the way you didn't want. I'd restore the log files from your backup, then it should start again. Afterwards you can stop it again, this time it should clean up the log files.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, I restored the backup files but had the same result.

Comment: dba.stackexchange.com is a better place for this question.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks a lot. I will share my question there.